# Asp:Textbox width

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Hello I am having this problem and I have looked all over google but nothing seems to help.

I have two Text boxes, and I just want both to be the same width. One is a multiline textbox and the other is a singleline text box. When i set both the widths of these text boxes only the Multiline box goes the correct width the singleline text box just seems to ignore it, but if I give the Single line text box the textmode of Multiline it works fine?

Can anyone see why?

```css
.container > * 
{
    display: inline-block;
} 
.labelspace
{
    padding-top:1%;
    padding-left:2.5%;
    width:50%;
}
.formfield *
{
    vertical-align:text-top;
}

.headfont
{
    font-size:11pt;
}

.answerspace
{
    padding-top:1%;
    padding-left:15px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="labelspace">
    <div class="formfield">
      <asp:Label ID="lblComments" runat="server">
        <p class="headfont"><strong>Additional Comments?</strong></p>
      </asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>&nbsp;
  <div class="answerspace">
    <div class="formfield">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" TextMode="Multiline" Rows="5" width="350px"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="labelspace">
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server">
      <p class="headfont"><strong>Your email address</strong></p>
    </asp:Label>
  </div>&nbsp;
  <div class="answerspace">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" Width="350px"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Had a look at this question before i posted and it didnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of these elements in your CSS rather than trying to use properties on the ASP components.

Update the ASP of those elements like so to add the `CssClass` attribute:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" CssClass="text-field" runat="server" TextMode="Multiline" Rows="5" />
```

Then target those elements with CSS:

```
.text-field {
  width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Ive tried this and still no luck it doesnt seem to even pick up that ive set the #txtEmail or #txtComments is there anything else i need to put in my HTML/Css?

Comment: @T.quant Come to think of it, ASP might be aliasing the IDs with additional information. I've updated my solution above to use the `CssClass` ASP attribute.